# A simple question regarding derivatives and tangents

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f'(\gamma)$ exists. When the definition of the derivative is introduced it is conventionally motivated by the secant argument and it seems quite intuitive. But how do we we know that $f'(\gamma)$ is the rate of change of the tangent that takes on the same value as $f$ when evaluated at $\gamma$? Is it possible to in a more rigorous sense prove that $f'(\gamma)$ cannot be anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it would be possible to prove your statement only in the limited number of cases (e.g. if the graph of $ f (x) $ is a circle arc) where you have an independent definition of a tangent. Otherwise, the tangent is defined using the derivative, and thus your statement is true - by definition. Note that the definition via derivative also includes some pathological cases such as $ f(x)=x^2 sin (1/x) $ (for $ x=0 $) where it is hard to 'intuitively' define a tangent.